# What's the word for someone who espouses "rather fail than wonder"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there some word/term/phrase for a person who takes risks or just tries (something) without worrying about the failures just because he/she doesn't want to give up without trying?

`Risk-taker` might be a potential candidate for such a word but I don't think it is apt enough.

> Getting into Oxford isn't a piece of a cake by any means, as it is world's top ranked university; but Oxford couldn't resist this __________ lad, who didn't want to wonder all his life whether he could have secured admission.

Comment: Why is risk-taker not apt enough?

Comment: I would say they're a "slogan-writer".

Comment: Please give us an example sentence.

Comment: @Josh: risk-taker by itself implies a focus on _them willingly taking risks_, in the sense that they tend to play fast and loose (compared to slow and calculated). Which seems to be different from OP's focus, which is more about _not being hesitant_ (i.e. "better do something than do nothing"), taking a risk only when no surefire approach exists.

Comment: I think it depends on the context, really, in terms of what is at risk.  This behaviour in a surgeon would be **reckless**, whereas the same behaviour in someone building a hobby woodwork project in their garage might be **optimistic** or **adventurous**.

Comment: @Josh I hope Flater has elaborated well why it's not suitable in the context. Thanks, Josh. Just to add to what he said, it's to be used in a situation when the person does not simply follows what he/she has heard about something but want to go by his own experiences after trying.

Comment: @Davo Take this as an example - Getting into Oxford isn't a piece of a cake by any means as it is world's top ranked university but it couldn't resist this <add the word/phrase here> lad who didn't want to wonder all his life whether he could have secured an admit and would reach to any conclusion only after trying himself.

Comment: I edited your question to include most of that example. I'd say you're looking for **plucky** as a descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting into Oxford isn't a piece of a cake by any means, as it is world's top ranked university; but Oxford couldn't resist this **plucky** lad, who didn't want to wonder all his life whether he could have secured admission.

From MW:

> **[Plucky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plucky)**
>
> spirited, brave

Comment: According to Grammarly, it means `Having or showing pluck, courage or spirit in trying circumstances.` I don't think it fits well either. It falls more towards `brave/courageous` but I want some word/phrase for someone who _doesn't give up without trying_ irrespective of how difficult the task may seem.

Answer (score 0):

**Daring** might be the word you're looking for.

> **Daring**
>
> venturesomely bold in action or thought

Alternatively, **venturesome** itself might also do the trick...

> **Venturesome**
>
> Inclined to court or incur risk or danger

...But personally, my choice would be **Audacious**, as it encompasses the other two quite well.

> **Audacious**
>
> intrepidly daring

(all definitions from MW)